# How to align duplicates on same row in excel for a certain amount of columns

Tags: html, css, vba, excel, macros

[Picture example of aligning needed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8UuKD.png)

Hello, I need help to align duplicates on the same row but extend it over a few columns on each side of these main columns. So for example A and K must be compared to align on the same row BUT columns on each side of A & K must be moved with it e.g column A-I and K- Q must move together to align together based on duplicates in col A and K. Example of what I want is shown in picture attached.

The code below does not included code to insert a line after each realigned duplicate group...please can you help with what code to use to insert a blank line after after each group of duplicates? - Represented in pic above.

The code is below: Will this work?

```
Sub HighlightDups()
    Dim i, LastRowA, LastRowB
    LastRowA = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    LastRowB = Range("K" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Columns("A:I").Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
    Columns("K:Q").Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
    For i = 1 To LastRowA
        If Application.CountIf(Range("K:Q"), Cells(i, "A")) > 0 Then
            Cells(i, "A").Interior.ColorIndex = 36
        End If
    Next
    For i = 1 To LastRowB
        If Application.CountIf(Range("A:I"), Cells(i, "K")) > 0 Then
            Cells(i, "K").Interior.ColorIndex = 36
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
Sub TEST()
    I = 1
    While I <= Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row And I <= Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
        If Range("A" & I) > Range("B" & I) Then
            Range("A" & I).Insert xlShiftDown
        ElseIf Range("A" & I) < Range("B" & I) Then
            Range("B" & I).Insert xlShiftDown
        Else
            If I > 1 Then
                If Range("A" & I - 1) <> Range("A" & I) And Range("B" & I - 1) <> Range("B" & I) Then
                    Range("A" & I, "B" & I).Insert xlShiftDown
                    I = I + 1
                End If
            End If
        End If
        I = I + 1
    Wend
End Sub
```

And about the color, you can use **Conditional format** to color only the ones that is not blank

Comment: Hi MuljayLee Thanks for the code but unfortuntely, it doesnt work. It just shifts the first column down to the end of the sheet and highlights the dups which I dont actually need in the end. Its a 15k row document with lots to compare so hoping a code will sort this out for me! Thank you though